# JsException: TypeError: Undefined and null dont have properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I searched everywhere to find the solution, but I find none of them are relevant to mine.

I tried to store a variable in local storage, but I'm getting the below error:

```
raise MakeError('TypeError',
JsException: TypeError: Undefined and null dont have properties (tried getting property 'setItem')
```

So I checked whether it is running on browser,

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('You are on the browser')
    if(message1!='undefined'){
        console.log("message1 is not undefined")
        window.localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage",message1);
    }
    
  }
```

Before giving the error, it printed "You are in the browser" in console, which I gave in the code to test

[output in console before giving the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3IRV.png)

I don't understand what is the cause, and why is it not able to store the variable in the local storage.

The tech stack I use are Javascript, React, python, and Js2py library to pass input from Python to Javascript.

Comment: Did you mean `if(message1 !== undefined){` or `if(typeof message1!== 'undefined'){`

Comment: I am getting a similar error. Have you found a way to resolve the bug?

Comment: I believe local storage is linked with DOM which is not supported by js2py